# Umbraco 7 Razor - find parent

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm using Umbraco 7 and I want a partial view to render a left nav starting at a certain point up the tree where it finds a page with a certain property set.

I've tried this but it only works from a fixed depth 1 layer down in the tree. I want to do this from any depth within the site and have it recurse back up until it finds an item and have that be the root for the left nav.

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage

@{
    @* Get the item above this one that has a property of resetLeftNav ticked *@
    var root = CurrentPage.AncestorOrSelf(1).Children.Where("resetLeftNav").First(); 
}

<ul class="nav left-nav">
    @foreach(var page in root.Children)
    {
        <li class="">
            <a href="@page.Url">@page.Name</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use:

```
var root = Model.Content.AncestorsOrSelf().First(
                 x => x.GetPropertyValue<bool>("resetLeftNav")
              );
```

The only difference is that you were looking for a single ancestor. Mine looks for them all which allows me to do the check and then take the first one.

Comment: You just beat me by 4min, my answer was very similar 
`CurrentPage.Ancestors().FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetPropertyValue<bool>("resetLeftNav"));`

Comment: Thanks for the responses ... I have dropped that in but I get an error:
Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type.

Comment: I've edited my answer to use `Model.Content` instead of `CurrentPage` which as you state is a dynamic object.

Comment: Actually I've just noticed that I now have to use xxx.GetProperty("PropertyName") to address my content's properties. Whereas when I used the dynamic object I could just use xxx.PropertyName.
Thanks

Is there any way to do the above using the dynamic object as I think it is preferable when addressing property values.

Comment: Well that's a matter of opinion. Personally I don't think so :) If you are worried about using "magic strings", the dynamic approach is basically the same only without the quotes - you're assuming there is a property with that particular name. At least with my way I could have a class with key property aliases as string `const` values. Also using dynamic is slower. Either way, no there isn't an overload that allows you to do this, sorry.